# How to set expire_in in OAUTH 2.0?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using `OAuth 2.0` with spring for token generation and I want to set `expire_in` manually so token can expire as per my criteria. Any one help me?

This is my response:

```
{
    access_token: "c7a6cb95-1506-40e7-87d1-ddef0a239f64"
    token_type: "bearer"
    expires_in: 43199
    scope: "read"
}
```

Answer (score -10, accepted):

```
public interface OAuth2AccessToken {

    public static String BEARER_TYPE = "Bearer";

    public static String OAUTH2_TYPE = "OAuth2";

    /**
     * The access token issued by the authorization server. This value is REQUIRED.
     */
    public static String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

    /**
     * The type of the token issued as described in <a
     * href="http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-7.1">Section 7.1</a>. Value is case insensitive.
     * This value is REQUIRED.
     */
    public static String TOKEN_TYPE = "token_type";

    /**
     * The lifetime in seconds of the access token. For example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will
     * expire in one hour from the time the response was generated. This value is OPTIONAL.
     */
    public static String EXPIRES_IN = "expires_in";

    /**
     * The refresh token which can be used to obtain new access tokens using the same authorization grant as described
     * in <a href="http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-6">Section 6</a>. This value is OPTIONAL.
     */
    public static String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";

    /**
     * The scope of the access token as described by <a
     * href="http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-22#section-3.3">Section 3.3</a>
     */
    public static String SCOPE = "scope";

    /**
     * The additionalInformation map is used by the token serializers to export any fields used by extensions of OAuth.
     * @return a map from the field name in the serialized token to the value to be exported. The default serializers 
     * make use of Jackson's automatic JSON mapping for Java objects (for the Token Endpoint flows) or implicitly call 
     * .toString() on the "value" object (for the implicit flow) as part of the serialization process.
     */
    Map<String, Object> getAdditionalInformation();

    Set<String> getScope();

    OAuth2RefreshToken getRefreshToken();

    String getTokenType();

    boolean isExpired();

    Date getExpiration();

    int getExpiresIn();

    String getValue();

}
```

Answer (score 40):

It can be set with a `ClientBuilder` obtained from a `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("client")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
            .scopes("app")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(30);
    }

    // ... additional configuration
}
```

or directly on `DefaultTokenServices` depending on your need.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        // optionally here you could just get endpoints.getConsumerTokenService()
        // and cast to DefaultTokenServices and just set values needed

        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(endpoints.getTokenStore());
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(endpoints.getClientDetailsService());
        tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(endpoints.getTokenEnhancer());
        tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(60);

        endpoints.tokenServices(tokenServices);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

configure your oauth configuration changing your Bean TokenServices and setting **accessTokenValiditySeconds** property :

```xml
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="1" />
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also configure the `DefaultTokenServices` in the [`application.yaml` file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml).

```yaml
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client-id
      clientSecret: client-secret
      authorized-grant-types: authorization_code,refresh_token,password
      scope: openid
      access-token-validity-seconds: 30
```

Comment: security.oauth2.client.access-token-validity-seconds = 30

Answer (score 2):

- Create a custom class of AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider and override the parent

  ```
  public method obtainAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details, AccessTokenRequest request)
  ```
- In the overridden method of your custom class, call upon the program logic of its parent class:

  ```
  DefaultOAuth2AccessToken token = super.obtainAccessToken(details, request);
  ```
- This will return an AccessToken.
  Now, you just have to manipulate the expired value of that token directly, by providing a timestamp from the past
  `token.setExpiresIn(int timestamp)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using grails security oauth2 provider
you can only change grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices

// Place your Spring DSL code here    

beans = {

  tokenServices(DefaultTokenServices){
    accessTokenValiditySeconds =  600;
    tokenStore = ref('tokenStore')
    supportRefreshToken = true;
    clientDetailsService = ref('clientDetailsService')
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also was searching for this answer and tried proposed solution from DeezCashews. But it didn't work for me, because there is a part of code which firstly check if this value is set in in column access_token_validity table oauth_client_details and only then greps value from tokenServices. So if your "expires_in" is set in oauth_client_details table, then you need to change it there.

Code which checks validity property in db :

```
    protected int getAccessTokenValiditySeconds(OAuth2Request clientAuth) {
    if (clientDetailsService != null) {
        ClientDetails client = clientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId(clientAuth.getClientId());
        Integer validity = client.getAccessTokenValiditySeconds();
        if (validity != null) {
            return validity;
        }
    }
    return accessTokenValiditySeconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As such I don't think there is any policy to do that so. But there is one way which can lead to success.
Just use refresh_token API to make the current access_token invalid. :D
Simple is that.