# Why is my Spring oauth server always returning the same access token?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, access-token

I'm using `Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE` and `spring-boot 1.5.3.RELEASE`.  I want to serve oauth access tokens to applications with the proper credentials.  I'm using the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore` class to do this.  However, I'm noticing that each time I connect with a client to my server that I have set up with OAuth, **the server repeatedly returns the same access token, even after server restarts.**  My OAuth server configuration is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
        so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
        mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/(users|clients)/.*" request-matcher="regex"
        create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        use-expressions="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/([^/].*?)/tokens/.*"
            access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('write')"
            method="DELETE" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/.*"
            access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
            method="GET" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/clients/.*"
            access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
            method="GET" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
    </http>

    <!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
        so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
        mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
    <http pattern="/me/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/me" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="sparklr2" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="sparklr2/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                <user name="marissa" password="koala" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="paul" password="emu" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="authenticationKeyGenerator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.UniqueAuthenticationKeyGenerator" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="tokenEnhancer" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenEnhancer"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter" />

    <bean id="requestFactory"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="approvalStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:client-credentials />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" entry-point-ref="entry"
        resource-id="myclientAssignment" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <bean id="entry" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="/assignment" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <oauth:client client-id="${myclient.client.id}"
            authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        access-token-validity="30"
            scope="read,write" secret="${myclient.client.secret}" />
    </oauth:client-details-service> 

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    <http pattern="/api/**"  
                  create-session="never"
                  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
                  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
     <anonymous enabled="false" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/**"
                             access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>

     <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                             before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
     <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
   </http>

</beans>
```

Here's the shell script I'm using to connect to my local server to retrieve the token ...

```
#!/bin/bash

ret=$(curl http://localhost:8080/myproject/oauth/token \
  -u "myclientid:mysecret" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials")
echo $ret > /tmp/out
cat /tmp/out
access_token=$( sed -e 's/^.*"access_token":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/' /tmp/out )
echo $access_token
```

**Edit:**

Per Hans' request, here is an example access token

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwiZXhwIjoxNDk2ODQ4NDAzLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX0NMSUVOVCJdLCJqdGkiOiI4OGMxZjkzZC0wNmRhLTRmYTAtOTM1OS0yZWMxYzU5MWJlMGIiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ6aW5jbGVhcm5pbmcifQ.Pf-rjPDj0ZhrNOYuhA0tK8lPLLCzlkqUuFFjb48xskA
```

and here is a second access token

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIiwid3JpdGUiXSwiZXhwIjoxNDk2OTUzNTg0LCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX0NMSUVOVCJdLCJqdGkiOiIxM2I5M2M4Ni05MmIwLTQyY2UtYjFkNS1lZjRiNmZhNzJkMzgiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJ6aW5jbGVhcm5pbmcifQ.GfSHA_JcQg2WHYCI81lunMFIhxdX6REc4goshB2Lck0
```

Comment: why shouldn't it return the same token since it is still valid

Comment: It returns the same token even the next day.  Is there something in my configuration that makes the token never expire?

Comment: @Dave please take a look at answers for similar questions [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311651/how-to-set-expire-in-in-oauth-2-0) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994788/spring-oauth2-access-token-expiry-time).

Comment: YOu're talking about adding "<property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="30" />" to my "<bean id="tokenServices"" configuration?  If so, I gave this a go, rebuilt and restarted everything, but I'm still getting served up the same access token each time, even after the 30 seconds specified in the directive.

Comment: Looks like your accessTokenValiditySeconds setting is not getting applied. Have you tried setting it through `ClientDetailsService` bean ? Can you empty the database of tokens  ? and try something like `<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails"> <oauth:client client-id .... "${myclient.client.secret}" access-token-validity="30" /> </oauth:client-details-service>`

Comment: I updaed my quesiton to include the ocnfiguraiton you suggested.  Still the same result.  INterestingly even when I delete all the access tokens from my database, the same token is issued (it begins with "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9".  Isn't that weird?

Comment: Please check the full contents of the token. Apparently your server is issuing a "structured" token called JWT. Hence the header - the part before the first "." in the value - will always be the same. You can decode the full JWT at jwt.io.

Comment: Moreover: if your JWT doesn't contain timestamp related fields like `iat` and `exp` then indeed the contents may always be the same.

Comment: Upon looking closer at the token, there are two "."s in the token.  The sections before the first "." and bewteen the first and second "." are both identical.  The part after the last "." is different.  However, on the server side, every time I submit the access token back to the server, I get this message, " [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore] (default task-5) Failed to find access token for token ..." in which "..." is the token we refer to above.

Comment: "Failed to find access token for token" can be acceptable scenario based on your set up.  This log message may show up because you have set short expire time (30 seconds), so token may have expired before you use it, after it was issued. Other reason could be because you have `supportRefreshToken` set to true, refresh token is used to process the request when your access token is expired.

Comment: You can try couple of things. First, Try removing  `supportRefreshToken` from set up and verify you see some kind of error message when access token has expired. Second, you can increase the `access-token-validity` to higher value ( 600 seconds ). See if these settings change anything.

Comment: Can you inspect access token json response from `/oauth/token`for  `expires_in` & `refresh_token` fields ?

Comment: @Veeram, as you can see from the shell script I have in my question, the token definitely hasn't expired (all commands execute one after anothre without a wait).  I tried setting '<property name="supportRefreshToken" value="false" />' but the "Failed to find access token error remains."  I don't understand what you want me to do as instructed by your last comment.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I just wanted to check the `expiry_in` field in the access token json response and verify if it is active. I'm not sure how the db row looks like. Does it have some kind of expiry field for you to check ? The shell script only shows the request for access token. I'm not sure how the resource is accessed after you get the token. The log message you have is logged at info level, so its definitely not a error/warn condition.

Comment: No, there is no expiry field in teh database.  I set up my oauth_access_token table consistent with how the JdbcTokenStore class requires it -- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java .  I think they encrypt that information into the "token" blob field, no?  Anyway, I'm a novice at this so you may know that answer better than I.

Comment: Can you add a sample token to the question?

Comment: @HansZ, sure thing.  I have edited my quesiton with a sample access token.

Comment: it's a structured access token, a JWT; you can decode it at https://jwt.io; it shows that an expiry timestamp (`exp`) and a unique identifier (`jti`) are included which should differ each time so my guess is that only the header is the same each time, not actually the payload and the signature; perhaps you can paste a 2nd sample to confirm

Comment: You bet.  I have pasted a second access token.

Answer (score 4):

This is sample regular access token which when issued will have `30` seconds expiration for your configuration.

You should see the info message (Failed to find access token for token) at the time a new token is issued.

```
{
  "access_token": "e057a4f3-9872-4b97-803e-938ad6ef32db",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "f9a7ea9a-0fd1-45a9-b8ae-de87eaf61787",
  "expires_in": 30,
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

This is expected behavior as spring looks into database to verify if the access token for the authentication is already issued.

Subsequent requests until the expiry of token (`30s`) will not show the message. This message will show up again after old access token is expired and when new token is issued and it continues.

The below line is where that info message is displayed from

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java#L168

Refresh token is set to expire in 30 days by default. The similar log message will appear again when the refresh token expires.

It should work similar for JWT access token too.

This is the sequences of log messages when a new token is issued when you run the application in `DEBUG` logging level.

```
2017-06-06 14:06:51.339 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for authentication org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@8e69d9c0: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER
2017-06-06 14:06:51.346 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2017-06-06 14:06:51.346 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [select token_id, token from oauth_access_token where token_id = ?]
2017-06-06 14:06:51.347  INFO 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for token e057a4f3-9872-4b97-803e-938ad6ef32db
2017-06-06 14:06:51.442 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2017-06-06 14:06:51.443 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into oauth_access_token (token_id, token, authentication_id, user_name, client_id, authentication, refresh_token) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
2017-06-06 14:06:51.450 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
2017-06-06 14:06:51.452 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL update
2017-06-06 14:06:51.452 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [insert into oauth_refresh_token (token_id, token, authentication) values (?, ?, ?)]
2017-06-06 14:06:51.455 DEBUG 28732 --- [nio-9191-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : SQL update affected 1 rows
```

Comment: So what you are sayhing is every time I see the message "Failed to find access token for token", it is because ther eis a new access token being issued?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there may be little bit more to it but at least that whats the code is looking like and testing/ log messages confirms that behavior. Unfortunately there is no javadoc to confirm the behavior. You have to note all those logs are logged at info/debug level. You can ask here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth to hear from the spring dev.

Comment: Additionally,  I would recommend adding extra test cases just to safeguard against the library changes when upgrading to newer oath spring version if that helps you.

Comment: I put a bounty on this bad boy so I don't have go asking in all these differnet places.  What specific test cases are you referring to?  You're going to have to spell this out for me -- I don't know anything about this stuff.

Comment: I was referring  to include a test case each for new access token and new refresh access token which will call [readAccessToken](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java#L156) and [readRefreshToken](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JdbcTokenStore.java#L222) respectively and assert for null value.

Comment: You can find a similar test case here for [readAuthenticaion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/TokenStoreBaseTests.java#L42) in the spring libraries which asserts for null authentication when token doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why i am getting same access token for multiple login request?**

Ashwani has given answer like below in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/88942)

> Access Tokens have fixed Life-Time.
>
> Until that period has not expires, access token remains the same.
> **During that period if you request access token you will receive the same string but will have reset expiration. It would only happen if
> Location, Password etc are exactly same as previous request**.
> Otherwise new token generated. Sometimes Salesforce resets the
> expiration time for last expired token and return in response.

### Short-lived access tokens and long-lived refresh tokens

There is no way to expire those tokens directly, so instead, the tokens are issued with a short expiration time so that the application is forced to continually refresh them, giving the service a chance to revoke an application’s access if needed.

---

`@Dave, As you have told that, there is no expiry field, so it is non-expiring access token`.

### Non-expiring access tokens

Non-expiring access tokens are the easiest method for developers. If you choose this option, it is important to consider the trade-offs you are making.

It isn’t practical to use self-encoded tokens if you want to be able to revoke them arbitrarily. As such, you’ll need to store these tokens in some sort of database, so they can be deleted or marked as invalid as needed.

Note that even if the service intends on issuing non-expiring access tokens for normal use, you’ll still need to provide a mechanism to expire them under exceptional circumstances, such as if the user explicitly wants to revoke an application’s access, or if a user account is deleted.

Non-expiring access tokens are much easier for developers testing their own applications. You can even pre-generate one or more non-expiring access tokens for developers and show it to them on the application details screen. This way they can immediately start making API requests with the token, and not worry about setting up an OAuth flow in order to start testing your API.

In summary, use non-expiring access tokens when:

1. you have a mechanism to revoke access tokens arbitrarily
2. you don’t have a huge risk if tokens are leaked
3. you want to provide an easy authentication mechanism to your
   developers
4. you want third-party applications to have offline access to users’
   data

**Resource Link:** [Acess token lifetime](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/)

---

How to refresh access token? Rules are given here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

**How to issue an access token are given here:**

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |  Owner   |
 |          |
 +----------+
      v
      |    Resource Owner
     (A) Password Credentials
      |
      v
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
 |         |>--(B)---- Resource Owner ------->|               |
 |         |         Password Credentials     | Authorization |
 | Client  |                                  |     Server    |
 |         |<--(C)---- Access Token ---------<|               |
 |         |    (w/ Optional Refresh Token)   |               |
 +---------+                                  +---------------+

        Figure 5: Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow
```

The flow illustrated in Figure 5 includes the following steps:

(A)  The resource owner provides the client with its username and
password.

(B)  The client requests an access token from the authorization
server's token endpoint by including the credentials received
from the resource owner.  When making the request, the client
authenticates with the authorization server.

(C)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
the resource owner credentials, and if valid, issues an access
token.

**The authorization server MUST follow the rules:**

o  require client authentication for confidential clients or for any
client that was issued client credentials (or with other
authentication requirements),

o  authenticate the client if client authentication is included, and

o  validate the resource owner password credentials using its
existing password validation algorithm.

**Resource Link:** https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-47

Comment: Thank for htis thorough explanation however I'm not clear about how to change my configuration based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration you use a JdbcTokenStore :

So, you have to check the table oauth_client_details : you must have a row with a column access_token_validity where you can change in live the duration in seconds.

Another solution is to delete that row and redeploy your application. Your configuration will create the row again with the value you specified in your configuration and that you were speaking about in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late to post an answer to this question but here is what I think should be considered.

When configuring an Authorization server, one of the parameters is the **`accessTokenValiditySeconds`**.

**the point here is that it is your solution:**

Here is an example of configuring the Authorization server.

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(ParamsConfig.TRUSTED_CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(ParamsConfig.TRUSTED_CLIENT_SECRET))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(10)
                .scopes(ParamsConfig.OAUTH_SECURITY_SCOPE)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(ParamsConfig.OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_GRANT_TYPE)
                .authorities(ParamsConfig.OAUTH_SECURITY_AUTHORITIES)
                .resourceIds(ParamsConfig.OAUTH_SECURITY_RESOURCE_ID);
    }
```

See the `accessTokenValiditySeconds` that describes two things:

1 - till what time this access token will be valid.

2 - till what time you will be getting the same Access token if you request for an access token.

**Note:**
*This configuration is in Java not xml.*

In your case, it should be `access-token-validity`.